# How would I make a longtable fill the last page vertically?

Tags: longtable

I'm designing a layout for a type of business report that I intend to dynamically fill the contents with using python code. To that end, each time I generate the report, it would have a different number of rows. This means that it could be one to many pages long. How would I make it so that, on the last page, the table extends all the way to the bottom with empty rows regardless of the number of rows on that last page?

Any assistance is very much appreciated!

I've attached a minimal example of the table itself:

```
\begin{longtable}{c | l | l | p{4.35in} | r}
    \hline \textbf{Status} & \textbf{Quantity} & \textbf{Product Code} & \textbf{Product Name} & \textbf{Unit Price}\\\hline
    \endhead
    \rowcolor{gray!15} □ & 3 Cases & 123456 & Chicken & 25.00\\
    □ & 11 Cases & 1234245 & Turkey & 21.50\\
    & & & &\\\hline
    \endlastfoot
\end{longtable}
```

I've also included a sample render of how I wanted it to look (keeping in mind the empty space on top and bottom are just the headers and footers of the page respectively, so they should go up to the edge of each page's margin). Also, the thicker horizontal lines are not part of the table, but rather the header/footer, so no need to worry about those.

Thank you for your time and help in advance!

[image: Sample render of how I want it to look]

Comment: unrelated but don't use `\noindent` before longtable

Comment: Thanks for the tip David! I will make the adjustment on my end.

Comment: How empty?  Would one really big row do or do you need alternating colors?

Comment: One really big white row at the end or several smaller white rows would be fine - alternating colors are not necessary for this part. All that's needed is the vertical column lines all the way down the page on the last page that the table extends to.